# prevent autocomplete/suggestions on android phones and prevent double space becoming period

Tags: javascript, android, html

How can I stop android phones changing double space tap to a period and prevent autocomplete/suggestions with javascript?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to create something that disables this on other applications/Android as a whole or are you trying to achieve this within your own application?

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I'm not looking to do this within an app. I want to prevent these actions within a textbox in an asp.net page with the use of javascript if needed. I have validation that gets overriden by these two events.

Comment: I think i've been looking at this stuff so long i've gone crazy! adding automcoplete ="off" (which i'm sure i'd tried many times) within my textbox now works.  However, I still need to prevent double space being replaced by a period.